# jQuery slidedown div between list boxes

Tags: jquery

I currently have a page with four list boxes on it and imagine a button alongside each one, say:

```
List 1 <button1>
List 2 <button2>
List 3 <button3>
List 4 <button4>
```

I also have a `<"div#formEntry">` that holds a form with text fields, for users to enter information in.

My question is, depending which button I have pressed, I would like to slideDown this div immediately after the button I have pressed.

So if I have pressed `<button2>`, slideDown div between List 2 and List 3 etc.

Just some further info to clarify my requirement:

```
 - List 1 <button1>
 - List 2 <button2>
 - List 3 <button3>
 - List 4 <button4>
```

Based on this list, if I press `<button2>`, I would like my form `<"div#formEntry">` to appear immediately below List 2, under the list item and to the left and not under the button.

Comment: edit this to make it more understandable. completely unclear what you're describing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("button selector").click(function() {
    $("#formEntry").insertAfter(this).slideDown();
});
```

Clicking any of the buttons will move the form after the button and slidedown. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: thanks for that - exactly what I was after. will try it out and let you know how I get on.

Comment: I tried it - almost what I want but I would actually like the div inserted under the listbox item and not the button itself. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: `$("button selector").click(function() {
    $("#formEntry").insertAfter(this).parent().slideDown();
});`
I inserted a `.parent()` above, depending on your markup you may have to insert various `.parent()` until you reach the listbox.